# Metatrader5 - Python Integration - symbol_total() returns None

Tags: python, metatrader5

I'm trying to get the number of symbols of `metatrader5` and I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Link to the documentation: https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5symbolstotal_py

code:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
print("MetaTrader5 package author: ",mt5.__author__)
print("MetaTrader5 package version: ",mt5.__version__)

if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
    quit()

symbols=mt5.symbols_total()
if symbols>0:
    print("Total symbols =",symbols)
else:
    print("symbols not found") 
mt5.shutdown()
```

The problem is that the function is returning NoneType instead of a number.
Why it's returning a NoneType? How can i get the list of Symbols/Stocks?
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. If you are currently using a downloaded MT5 terminal from your broker, you can try using the [official MT5 terminal](https://www.metatrader5.com/) instead. That seemed to have fixed my issue. Don't forget to specify the path to the correct MT5 terminal.exe afterwards within the initialization function `initialize(path=...)`.

As to why this was causing an issue, I'm unsure myself. I happened across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028717/metatrader5-libarary-in-python-3-7) and it mentioned that there may have been modifications made by brokers.

Anyway, hope this works for you too!

---

To connect to your broker's server afterwards, within the MT5 terminal under Navigator->Accounts (Right Click)->Open an account->Search for your broker and enter your credentials.